# How to tally if a certain letter is in a row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

I Have a table like below

```
| ID | Code 1 | Code 2 | Code 3 | Code 4 |
| A  |  R     |  R     |  R     |  R     |
| B  |  T     |  R     |  T     |  R     |
| C  |  R     |  R     |  T     |  R     |
| D  |  T     |  T     |  T     |  R     |
```

I want to code in excel to count how many rows have 3 'R's, 2 R's, etc, and the same for T And make a table to tally that. How would I go about coding that?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Try `COUNTIF` and `IF` functions.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you add the helper columns for R and T, like the following image.

[image]

Using countif function to get the numbers of R and T for each row.

Then use countif function again to get the 3 'R's, 2 R's, etc.

[image]